# How can I link multiple JIRAs to one BitBucket Branch?

Tags: bitbucket, jira

Environment:  JIRA v7.5.2, Bitbucket Server 5.14

I have two JIRAs who's issue keys are 'JIR-01' and 'JIR-02'.  They're two different issues but are solved by the same code change.  I've been directed to create a single branch.

If I name the branch 'JIR-01-JIR-02' it will show up in JIRA only under JIR-01.
If I name the branch 'JIR-02-JIR-01' then it will show up in JIRA only under JIR-02.

Is there any way I can make the branch show up in both JIRA's?

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled [smart commits](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-smart-commits-in-bitbucket-server-802599018.html) you can commit to whatever Bitbucket branch and add a link to that branch in Jira by using this format:

```
<ignored text> <ISSUE_KEY> <ignored text> #<COMMAND> <optional COMMAND_ARGUMENTS>
```

For example if you want to link the commit to the issue ABC-123 you have to commit with this message:

```
Commit comment ABC-123
```

Comment: I'm looking to link 1 Branch to two JIRAs so that it'll show up in the 'Development' section of each JIRA.  I'm not sure this does it.